# triple integral pyramid bounds

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

I am still confused about how to set up bounds for double and triple integrals. My task is to set up bounds for a function that is a pyramid with edge coordinates $(5,+-5, 0)$, $(-5,+-5,0)$, $(0,0,4)$. it follows the order of $dydxdz$. I have already set the bound for $dz$ . it is $0$ to $4$. Can anyone show me how to solve it and explain how I need to think when setting up bounds. Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Before posting a question, kindly read [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to use LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I hope you enjoy your time being a part of this community!

Comment: Hint: try to sketch a picture and see if you can use some symmetry.

Comment: hi. I have scetched it. And see the symmetry. I see a linear function. But dont know how to set it up since there is 4 sides of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to express both x and y as functions of z, since z is the last bounds for the integral. As z goes from 0 to 4, both x and y goes from -5 to 5. So the functions will be:

$$x = \frac{5}{4}z$$
$$y = \frac{5}{4}z$$

and then the integral may be set up as:

$$\int_0^4 \int_{-\frac{5}{4}z}^{\frac{5}{4}z} \int_{-\frac{5}{4}z}^{\frac{5}{4}z} 1 dy dx dz$$

But, the symmetry argument would be easier... there is a easy formula for the volume of a pyramid.

Comment: Thank yoy for the answer. But unfortunately my capquiz is saying its the wrong answer. Dont know why

Comment: I don't about your capquiz, but $\int_0^h \int_{\frac{-l}{2h}z}^{\frac{l}{2h}z} \int_{\frac{-w}{2h}z}^{\frac{w}{2h}z} dxydydz = \frac{1}{3}lwh$, which is the formula for the volume of a pyramid.